# Converting Array.map + Promise.all to Observable

Tags: angular, reactjs, rxjs, observable

I have Vanilla.js (TypeScript) HTTP client that returned Promises, like so:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    friendsIds: number[];
}

class MyClient {

    getPersonInfo(personId: number): Promise<Person> {

        return fetch( '/people/' + personId)
            .then( r => r.json() as Person );
    }
}
```

My display code gets the details of each Person's friends, like so:

```
refresh(): void {

    client.getPersonInfo( 123 )
        .then( (person: Person) => {

            // array-of-promises:
            let friendsDetailsPromises: Promise<Person>[] = person.friendsIds.map( friendId => client.getPersonInfo( friendId  ) );

            // promise-of-array:
            let friendsDetailsAll     : Promise<Person[]> = Promise.all( friendsDetailsPromises );

            return friendsDetailsAll;
        } )
        .then( (friendsDetails: Person[]) => {

            // (do stuff for each Person)
        } )
        .catch( reason => console.error( reason ) );
}
```

I'm trying to move this over to Angular 2's built-in HTTP client which returns `Observable<T>` instead of `Promise<T>`, so far I have:

```
class MyClient {

    private http: HttpClient; 

    getPersonInfo(personId: number): Observable<Person> {

        return this.http.get<Person>( '/person/' + personId );
    }
}

refresh(): void {

    client.getPersonInfo( 123 )
        .flatMap( (person: Person) => {

            // ...now what?
        } )
        .subscribe(
            (friendsDetails: Person[]) => {

            // (do stuff for each Person)
            },
            err => console.error( err )
        )
    );
}
```

I'm stuck on what I'm supposed to do inside of `flatMap`.

I saw this QA which asks about converting `Promise.all` to `Observable` ( [Promise.all behavior with RxJS Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608025/promise-all-behavior-with-rxjs-observables) ) and the answer is to use `forkJoin` but also suggests `flatMap` and linking to this posting ( [RxJS Promise Composition (passing data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701304/rxjs-promise-composition-passing-data/34701912#34701912) ) but this problem doesn't resemble mine at all.

Comment: try `return Observable.combineLatest(person.friendsIds.map( friendId => client.getPersonInfo( friendId  ) )`

Comment: @HarryNinh How would that change if I move to use `Subject` instead of creating a new `Observable` for each request? (I assume Angular's HTTP client creates a new `Observable` for each request - but doesn't that defeat the point of it being "observable" in the first place, because it won't update its state?)

Comment: Sorry not crystal clear about your approach of how you're gonna use `Subject` here. For me `Observable` and `Promise` are very much serving the same purpose here in `Http`, if you were okay with having an array of `Promise`, what stops you from having an array of `Observable`?

Comment: @HarryNinh I didn't return a `Promise<T>[]` - I used `Promise.all` to convert it to `Promise<T[]>` and I returned that. I'm asking what the Observable equivalent of `Promise.all` is - and if there's a better, RxJS-idiomatic, approach.

Comment: Yes you didn't, but in the process you have already created `friendsDetailsPromises: Promise<Person>[]`, which is an array of promises. Same here, `Observable.combineLatest` is used to combine an array of `Observable` to a single `Observable<T[]>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Observable.forkJoin` which will wait for all sub observables to complete(same as Promise.all).

I find the below syntax which works(**Maybe not the best and wait for suggestions**)

```
this.http.get('list.json').switchMap(res => {                   
  return Observable.forkJoin(res.map(item => this.http.get(item + '.json')));  
})
```

Refer this **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yc85EauZaN3425wSd4pL?p=preview)**.

---

Sorry, Maybe this is a little late for it took some time to find new usage about rxjs5.