# RXJS avoid nested multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-subscriptions

I would like to transform below code snippet:

```
 this.dataUserSubscription = this.store$.pipe(select(selectUser)).subscribe(
            user => {
                this.store$.pipe(select(selectUserData, {user}), take(1))
                    .subscribe(userData => {
                        if (userData === null) {
                            this.store$.pipe(select(selectUserManagement, {user}), take(1)).subscribe(
                                userManagement => {
                                    this.store$.dispatch(saveUserDataToStore({
                                        user,
                                        userManagement
                                    }));
                                });
                        }
                    });
```

by avoid nested subscription. All examples, which I found, is per two subscriptions.

```
 this.dataUserSubscription = this.store$.pipe(select(selectUser),
    switchMap(user => this.store$.pipe(select(selectUserData, {user}))))
    .subscription(userData => {
        // logic
    })
```

But it is no proper solution for my example of code. 
Why is the proper step for fixing multiple nested subscriptions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid multiple nested subscriptions using RxJS operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416011/how-can-i-avoid-multiple-nested-subscriptions-using-rxjs-operators)

Comment: what is your use-case for this multiple subscription here? as per that you can choose your rxjs operator.

Comment: @Tal Ohana Nope. There are not related subscriptions. I need data from 1st subscription in second and last.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I need dispatch action, and for it need some different data. But also those selectors should be reloaded when change select user in Dropdown. That's why I need nested subscription - aut. refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Per RxJS best practices, your second example is a perfectly acceptable approach.

But per NgRx best practices, you can get rid of the nested subscription by just combining your selectors.

It's hard to say exactly *what* to do without seeing your `selector` files, but if you already have the `user` in the store, then you should be able to pull the user data out of the store without 2 selector calls.

Maybe something like:

```
const getDataForUser = createSelector(
    selectUser,
    selectUsers,
    (user, userDataDictionary) => userDataDictionary[user.id]
)
```

Then just use the one `getDataForUser` selector.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I need solution in pure rxjs, no double selector etc.

I should use multiple switchMap or what? I tried mixed solution, but without success.