# Non-returning async method

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using Typescript with es2017 as the compilation target, using Javascript's new `async` / `await`.

I currently have the following code to fetch some data from a TS service class (simplified):

```
class MyClass {

    public static async initialize(): Promise<void> {
        const data = await this.getItems();
        // do unrelated initialization stuff
        return new Promise<void>(() => {});
    }

    private static async getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
        return await Service.fetchData();
    }
}

class Service {
    public static async fetchData(): Promise<Item[]> {
        // Performs an XHR and returns a Promise.
    }
}
```

This works, but it would be a lot cleaner if `MyClass::initialize()` did not return anything, rather than returning `new Promise<void>(() => {});` However, this seems to be impossible, as any method/function that uses `await` **has to** be marked `async`, and any method/function that is marked as `async` **has to** return a `promise`.

Is there any way around this, or is there something I'm fundamentally not grasping?

Comment: "has to return a promise" does not apply to js. JavaScript `async` functions return a promise automatically, The function's return value (not necessarily a promise) resolves the promise returned when calling the function. Is Typescript different?

Comment: You should not write a `class` that has only static methods. Use an object literal instead.

Comment: Have a look at [`toVoid` from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240420/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi why is that?

Comment: @Niek A `class` should only be used for when objects need to be instantiated. It's inefficient (and confusing) otherwise. Object literals are just simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Async functions in TypeScript do need to be declared to return promises, but you don't actually need to return a promise from the function. You can just return the type of the promise value from the async function and it will be taken care of that it is wrapped in a promise.

So, for async functions that return a `Promise<void>`, you can just have an empty return or no return at all.

```
class Item
{
}

class MyClass 
{

    public static async VoidAsyncWithReturn(): Promise<void>
    {
        return;
    }

    public static async VoidAsyncWithoutReturn(): Promise<void>
    {
    }

    private static async AsyncReturningValue(): Promise<Item[]> 
    {
        var result: Item[] = new Array();
        return result;
    }

    private static async AsyncReturningPromise(): Promise<Item[]> 
    {
        var result: Promise<Item[]> = new Promise<Item[]>(() => { return new Array() });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type` in both the `MyClass::getItems()` and the `Service::fetchData()` methods.

Comment: @Niek Sorry, I got mixed up. I have corrected the answer.